# manifest.json, full width

Tags: sapui5, manifest

there seem to be 2 ways of telling the framework if the full screen width shell be used in a ui5 app:

[image]

If both are specified the upper one seems to overrule the bottom one.
Which of them should be used and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property in the config is for providing values to the Component of your application.

Whereas,

> "fullWidth" is part of the namespace "sap.ui" which takes priority as
>   it is a defined property for the manifest([Descriptor for
>   Application](https://help.sap.com/viewer/468a97775123488ab3345a0c48cadd8f/7.51.6/en-US/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html)).

Manifest is called from the Component which has this defined property and will take preference while running your application.

Comment: while you answer does explain the diffrence between them, my question was which one should be used, if you add that i can give your answer the green tic

Comment: Hello Erch, you should use the property in sap.ui namespace as it is meant for this(as per the documentation shared in the link) check the section "sap.ui namespace"